# ZipArchive ExtractToFile write to the disk with a delay

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I'm trying to write some code that wrap several dlls into my dll.
in my solution one of the projects is responsible for extracting an internal zip resource to the output dlls that are been used by the second project.
the reference to the second project is being performed only after the extraction is completed.
my problem is that on the first execution I get an exception of FileNotFoundException.
I believe that the issue is that the ZipArchive ExtractToFile is returning before the the writing is been flushed to the disk.

I would like to hear some thoughts on the subject (I thought about adding some kind of sleep after the extraction but it didn't feel right...)

my extraction code is:

```
private static void ExtractToDirectory(ZipArchive archive, string executionPath)
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(executionPath,entry.Name)))
        {
            entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(executionPath, entry.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When and how does that code run?

Comment: on the constructor of the first project.
at the end of the constracture (after that code was called) I'm referencing to the second project.

Comment: when I'm referencing to the second project with reflection the issue is not reproducible...
this means that the issue is that the loading of a static linked dlls is when accessing the first one and not when accessing each of them, right?

Answer (score 0):

How do you reference your second project at the end of the constructor of the first project? Maybe second project tries to read files in some static constructor or method, before first project unzips files. How big ZIP files do you actually have and how many files are in it?

Comment: I'm referencing to the second project at the end of the constructor and there is no static function that is referencing it before it.
when the reference is performed statically (explicit new to that type) the loading is failing but when I'm using reflection to create the instance everything works...

Comment: Can you post complete (relevant code) of first project's constructor and method in second project that consumes result of extraction?